# Java GUI Button unpressable

Tags: java, user-interface

Code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)

    {
.......


while(true)
{
if (source==button1)

                   {
                     //button1 code                       
                   }


if(source==button2) 

                  { 
                    // button2 code
                  }
} //while true


.....
  //some other code that I don't want it to execute until while breaks
}//action performed
```

So the problem is that when the above code is executed the GUI is stuck and no buttons can be pressed. If I remove the infinite loop, the rest of the code will be executed and stop my algorithm. Is there any work around for this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking the GUI thread. 
Try looking at the tutorial, which explains how to run user actions in a background thread.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Answer (score 1):

The while loop is a serious programming error. Making your program execute the loop in the Event Dispatcher Thread it gets unable to dispatch any other events (other button presses).

You have to eliminate the loop. Doing so the actionPerformed method will run in every button click (given you buttons have actionListeners...).